# Why do newlines in my CSS font-family break IE? How can I avoid this?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, character-encoding

My designer wanted Century Gothic, which is *not quite* web safe, so we decided lucida was an OK backup and I wrote a long stack of fallback fonts:

```
body {
font-family: "Century Gothic",
             "URW Gothic L",
             "Apple Gothic",
             "Lucida Grande",
             "Lucida Sans Unicode",
             "Trebuchet MS",
             "Lucida Sans",
              sans-serif;
}
```

This looks fine in Chrome, FF, Safari. When I check in IE (6, 7, and 8), no dice. Fonts everywhere on the site are an ugly serif typeface! I fire up IE 8 developer tools and see little rectangle characters in the declaration that seem to fall on the line breaks. I revise my CSS to

```
body {
font-family: "Century Gothic", "URW Gothic L", "Apple Gothic", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

and this works mint. Fine, problem solved, but if I want to format my CSS for readability why shouldn't I be able to? Why is my whitespace relevant? Is this a utf/iso charset issue? Do I just have to let long lines run long?

Comment: Interesting quirk.  Personally I prefer all-one-line css rules so that it is easier to find the selector I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a separate style sheet or is it styles you created in your  tag?  You may be able to pull it out into a .css file and that may stop the issue.

IMO let this one go.  This should be the exception not the rule for you to have a css rule that is this long.

Comment: It's in a separate stylesheet. Yeah, I'm not going to stress too hard, but it's annoying.

Comment: Ahh, IE. Is there anything you *can't* screw up?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your text editor is saving the css file with mac specific line-breaks (carriage-return).  Change the line breaks to unix (line-feed) and see if it comes out how you'd like.